# JQuery problem with html() handling in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, opera

I have following JS code (stripped to minimal size where problem still exists)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="debug">this is <em>test</em></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var string1 = $('#debug').html();
    var string2 = string1.replace(/<em>/g, '<strong>');
    string2 = string2.replace(/<\/em>/g, '</strong>');
    $('#debug').html( string2 );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In Firefox everything works and <em> tags are replaced with <strong>.

But in Opera <em>'s are stay in place. Furthermore, any other HTML tags are not captured by regexps at all.

Is there any way to fix this behaviour? I need not only to replace tags, but to parse their content too (href attributes for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opera returns tags as uppercase, e.g. `<EM>`. You need to change your regular expressions to work case-insensitively:

```
var string2 = string1.replace(/<em>/gi, '<strong>');
string2 = string2.replace(/<\/em>/gi, '</strong>');
```

Comment: @technix.in.ua Opera is just creating a normalized representation of the source HTML and chooses to make tag names uppercase. Firefox does the opposite and makes all tag names lowercase.

Comment: In addition to Firefox, Safari & Chrome also normalize to lowercase. Opera followed IE's TagSoup[tm] .innerHTML return value to be "compatible" but Opera in recent years has tried hard to distance itself from copying IE's bugs.  Generally speaking this makes more sense (IMHO) considering that XHTML tags and attributes are meant to be lowercase anyway.  In this case the IE/Opera normalization is whack. Tags upper, attributes lower (or camelCase), and only properly quoted on attributes with values set... but I digress...

Comment: I don't quite understand the assertation that tag and attribute names are "meant to be" lowercase. The logic for doing what IE does is very simple: IE invented innerHTML, so they are by definition correct and browsers who want to support it should figure out what IE does. (Of course it's now being standardised in HTML5, so when HTML5 is released this no longer applies.)

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use string methods when you can use DOM methods:

```
$("#debug em").each(function() {
    var newElem = document.createElement("strong");
    for (int i=0; i<this.childNodes.length; ++i) {
        newElem.appendChild(this.childNodes[i]);
    }
    this.parentNode.replaceNode(newElem, this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expressions aren't matching in Opera as it has normalised all HTML tags to uppercase try with //gi

However if you are doing more changes ("parsing their content"), I really would recommend doing proper DOM manipulation and not using regular expressions.